# Conditional select in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT UserID from Users as user
    INNER JOIN UserStatus as userStatus on u.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE
    --user.IsActive = 1
    --if user.IsActive = 0
        --userStatus.DeactivatedDate > @StartDate
        --userStatus.DeactivatedDate < @EndDate
```

So in general I want a query that gets me all results whose value matches the where statement without necessarily ignoring all of those results that do not. Kind of like a Venn diagram with the the left side of the circle and the middle filled in.  For the example I've shown, I want all users who are currently active and the users who are not active but were active within the given time frame (if I wanted the total number of users active at any point within a month, for instance).

I've tried doing things like

```
SELECT UserID from Users as user
    INNER JOIN UserStatus as userStatus on u.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE
    Case user.IsActive = 1
```

But that is obviously incorrect syntax.  I will also need to translate this to LINQ as well, so resources on that would be beneficial as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID from Users as user
    INNER JOIN UserStatus as userStatus on u.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE
     user.IsActive = 1 OR us.DeactvatedDate BETWEEN '2012-08-13' AND '2013-08-13'
```

This will do the job if you have any entry regarding date when a user got decativated.

In LINQ

```
var UID= from u in Users
         from s in UserStatus
         where u.UserID == s.UserID || (s.DeactivatedDate  >= @StartDate &&        
         s.DeactivatedDate <= @endDate)
         select u.userID
```

Comment: Hehe @ `decavitated`, whatever it means, it sounds deadly ;)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this will give you the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT  UserID 
FROM    Users U
JOIN    UserStatus US 
    ON  U.UserID = US.UserID
WHERE
        U.IsActive = 1
        OR (
                U.IsActive = 0
            AND US.DeactivatedDate > @StartDate
            AND US.DeactivatedDate < @EndDate
        )
```